# Is this using of dictionary thread-safe or not?

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

Here is two my variants of method, which returns a string, associated with enum value (kept in dictionary). First variant is slower, but thread-safe, second is faster, but i don't know, whether it is thread-safe or not. First:

```
string GetStringForEnum (SomeEnum e)
{
   string str = null;
   lock (someDictionary) //someDictionary is not used anywhere else (only in this method)
   { if (!someDictionary (e, out str)) { someDictionary.Add (e, "somehowCreatedString"); }
   return str;
}
```

Second variant:

```
string GetStringForEnum (SomeEnum e)
{
   string str = null;
   if (!someDictionary (e, out str))
   {
     lock (someDictionary) //someDictionary is not used anywhere else (only in this method)
     { if (!someDictionary (e, out str)) { someDictionary.Add (e, "somehowCreatedString"); }
   }
   return str;
}
```

Second variant is not used "lock" each time, but is it thread-safe or not?

Comment: Is this suppose to be real code?  I can't place `!someDictionary (e, out str)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 problems here:

- `lock (someDictionary)`  - this is dis-advised, even if the dictionary is not used elsewhere. It is a theoretical argument but the (future) code of the Dictionary class could lock on itself.
- `if (!someDictionary (e, out str))` without a lock. I assume this is a call to `TryGetValue()`. This simply is not thread-safe, your Read could be interrupted by a Write in another thread. This could end in all sorts of errors (index out of range, null reference). The errors will be very rare (= hard to reproduce).

Comment: "but the (future) code of the Dictionary class could lock on itself.". If dictionary was to do that, it would break a strong guideline of the [Framework Design Guidelines](http://www.amazon.com/Framework-Design-Guidelines-Conventions-Libraries/dp/0321545613) and this would also be a breaking change. It is therefore safe to assume that dictionary will never lock on itself.

Comment: @Steven - you're right, like is said 'theoretical'. The best practice is to use an instance that you control and hide as much as possible.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I must say I'm very pragmatic about this when writing LOB applications and simply lock on the private collection (when possible). On the other hand I'm very strict, when it comes to writing code for reusable libraries. It's all about context ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) on `Dictionary` has a section on thread safety:

> A `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` can support multiple readers
>   concurrently, **as long as the collection is not modified**. Even so,
>   enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe
>   procedure. In the rare case where an enumeration contends with write
>   accesses, the collection must be locked during the entire enumeration.
>   To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading
>   and writing, you must implement your own synchronization.
>
> For a thread-safe alternative, see `ConcurrentDictionary(Of TKey,
>   TValue)`.

So:

- [`TryGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) is safe to use from multiple threads because it is read-only. However, it is *not* safe when other code is writing the dictionary at the same time (which your code is doing).
- Adding a value is never safe unless you lock the dictionary.
- Using a `ConcurrentDictionary` is an easy solution to get going, but it may be no faster than your first version (I assume it's going to lock on every operation).

And a side note: Using a field that is not private (here the field is `someDictionary` and we don't know if it's `private` or not) as a `lock` target is not recommended because theoretically external code could also decide to `lock` it without your knowledge (practically this is not going to happen, but why not be theoretically correct as well?).

Comment: Small correction. You say "TryGetValue is safe to use from multiple threads because it is read-only.", but this only holds "as long as the collection is not modified". The examples given by the OP clearly show that he actually IS updating the dictionary, which make it *unsafe* to use `TryGetValue` outside a lock.unsafe. For the rest of your answer: +1.

Comment: @Steven: I should probably have made that explicit. Edited the answer accordingly, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

If you use .NET 4 you can use `ConcurrentDictionary` for thread safety.

Comment: Yeah, I would strongly recommend using the Collections from the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace, instead of using a lock.

If not possible then use ReaderWriterLockSlim.